# Execute helper function from Magento extension upgrade script

Tags: extensions, upgrade

I have created and maintain Magento extension (responsive banner slider) but have run into an issue.

I have added functionality based on the HTML5 picture element which will be supported by browsers in the future (the current implementation is a javascript polyfill implementation based on HTML5 specification). The picture element allows to deliver an appropriate image to every user depending on a variety of conditions like screen size, viewport size, screen resolution and thus saves bandwidth/load time on mobile devices. For this I have built functionality that will create smaller sized images for every banner that is uploaded through my extension.

FO user who upgrade from a previous version these smaller images will need to be batch created for all existing banner images. But what I cant seem to find out is how to trigger a helper function that will perform this action and is only run once after the upgrade from the current version to the future version which where this functionality will be implemented. I know how to write upgrade / data scripts but this only allows for database manipulation. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where did you get the idea that upgrade scripts are for db manipulation.
You can do anything with them.
If you want to use a helper I would suggest using the `data`folder.
Create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/data/[resource_setup]/upgrade-x.y.z-a.b.c.php`

```
<?php 
Mage::helper('some_helper')->doSomething($withThis);
```